# Spring social Facebook Profile provides only ID and name

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I have an issue with getting parameters others than `id` and `name` using `spring-social`.

Dependencies:

```
    <!-- Spring Social -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Social Facebook -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Configuration:

```
<security:http ...>
...
    <security:custom-filter before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="socialAuthenticationFilter" />
...
</security:http>
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    ...
    <security:authentication-provider ref="socialAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
<bean id="socialAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="inMemoryUsersConnectionRepository"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="socialUserDetailsService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="inMemoryUsersConnectionRepository"
      class="org.springframework.social.connect.mem.InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository">
    <constructor-arg name="connectionFactoryLocator" ref="connectionFactoryLocator"/>
    <property name="connectionSignUp" ref="connectionSignUp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator"
      class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry">
    <property name="authenticationServices">
        <list>
            <ref bean="facebookAuthenticationService"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter">
    <constructor-arg name="authManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <constructor-arg name="userIdSource" ref="userIdSource"/>
    <constructor-arg name="usersConnectionRepository" ref="inMemoryUsersConnectionRepository"/>
    <constructor-arg name="authServiceLocator" ref="connectionFactoryLocator"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="loginGuidAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userIdSource" class="org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource"/>

<bean id="facebookAuthenticationService"
      class="org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService">
    <constructor-arg name="apiKey" value="<myKey>"/>
    <constructor-arg name="appSecret" value="<mySecret>"/>
    <property name="defaultScope" value="email"/>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionSignUp" class="my.package.DefaultConnectionSignUp"/>
```

I have my own implementations of some of the required services, which I don't think are relevant. When I debug `execute` method in my implementation of `ConnectionSignUp` all of the users fields are null except for `name` and `id`.

```
@Override
public String execute(Connection<?> connection) {
    Connection<Facebook> fbConnection = (Connection<Facebook>) connection;
    fbConnection.getApi().userOperations().getUserProfile().getEmail(); //null
    fbConnection.getApi().userOperations().getUserProfile().getFirstName(); //null
    fbConnection.fetchUserProfile().getEmail(); //null
    fbConnection.fetchObject("me", User.class); //email == null
    ...
}
```

My jsp form:

```
    <form name='facebookSocialloginForm'
          action="<c:url value='/auth/facebook' />" method='POST'>
        <input type="hidden" name="scope" 
            value="public_profile,email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_likes"/>
        ...
    </form>
```

I **can access** users private `posts` and `likes` though. On my facebook account it says that the app has access to the email and other informations.

Any suggestions? If I've missed something important, please ask and I'll provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changes in facebook api might have caused this. Try the code below:

```
UserOperations userOperations = facebook.userOperations();
            String [] fields = { "id", "email",  "first_name", "last_name" };
            org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User profile = facebook.fetchObject
                    ("me", org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User.class, fields);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. To add some more details. It appears I've had two different versions of `spring-social-facebook` in two modules of my app and it was using the oldest one. After resolving this problem `getUserProfile()` method doesn't work **at all** `(Error message is (#12) bio field is deprecated for versions v2.8 and higher)`, since Facebook API v. 2.8 is not supported in v. 2.0.3.RELEASE. So untill the next release I believe it is the best (only?) solution.

Answer (score 0):

add public_profile,email to your scope variable while hitting facebook api,this will definately return you required data.